# Delete text between two characters

Tags: c++

I am working on a little programm rigth now and I am stuck. I have a

```
const char *dvar_hostname;
```

and I'm writing a word on this char array, f.e.

```
"[12]1234" or "1234"
```

So now I have to check if the word I wrote on that `char*` contains `[` and `]`, and if so delete the brackets and the text in it, so

```
"[12]1234"
```

becomes

```
"1234"
```

it needs to be written on the `const char*` at the end again(so I think you would need to use a temporary string). I tried something like that:

```
dvar_hostname = "[12]1234";
            string host = string(dvar_hostname);
            if(host.substr(1) == "[")
            {
                string str = string(dvar_hostname);
                unsigned first = str.find("]");
                unsigned last = str.find("[");
                string newString = str.substr (first,last-first);
                const char *tempHostName = newString.c_str();
            }
```

but that didn't turned out as I wanted too, so any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

```
if(strcmp(dvar_hostname2, Dvar_GetString("sv_hostname")))
        {
            dvar_hostname2 = Dvar_GetString("sv_hostname");
            dvar_hostname1 = Dvar_GetString("sv_hostname");
            printf("sv_hostname[w/ Clantag]: %s\n", dvar_hostname1);
            bool open_bracket = true;
            bool end = false;

            size_t pos_open = 0;
            size_t pos_close = 0;

            string dh(dvar_hostname1);//get string value
            while(!end){
                pos_open = dh.find('[');
                pos_close = dh.find(']');


                if(pos_open == string::npos || pos_close == string::npos || pos_close < pos_open){
                    end = true;
                }else{
                    dh.erase(pos_open, pos_close - pos_open + 1);
                }
            }
            dvar_hostname1 = dh.c_str();
            printf("sv_hostname[w/o Clantag]: %s\n", dvar_hostname1);
        }
```

this prints out: `sv_hostname[w/ Clantag]: [{TM}]Twain` and `sv_hostname[w/o Clantag]: Twain, btw`dvar_hostname1&2`are booth`const char*`
then elsewhere I'm doing this:

```
if(!strcmp(Player(Client).getGT(), dvar_hostname1)
```

//Player(Client).getGT() returns "Twain" in this case... 
any idea why it doesn't continue with the code after this if statement?

Comment: If you are using c++11,   `std::regex_replace(host, std::regex{"\\[.*\\]"}, "")`

Comment: @Praveen no i'm not sry :(

Comment: *t needs to be written on the const char* at the end again* -- Why do you "need" this "need"?  You're changing the string, so what's the reason for this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various answers and comments contain a great deal of implicit speculation about the actual requirements. From your example, some strings will start with a '[' followed by a few characters followed by a ']', and you want to delete everything up to and including the ']'. That's simple:

```
const char* str = "[12]1234";
char target[20]; // or whatever size is appropriate
const char* loc = strchr(str, ']');
strcpy(target, loc ? loc + 1 : str);
```

If you have additional unstated requirements (such as characters before the '[' that have to be preserved, or multiple sets of characters enclosed in square brackets) you should say what those requirements are so that you'll get meaningful answers instead of guesses and overkill.

EDIT, per @TomerW:

```
const char* str = "[12]1234";
const char* loc = strchr(str, ']';
return loc ? loc + 1 : str;
```

Comment: this is perfect simple and clean and it also fixed a other problem :)

Comment: if you neglected the possibility the '[' is preceded by characters, you can be even faster with `return (loc ? loc+1 : str); // skipping the copy`

Comment: @TomerW -- even better!

Answer (score 7):

You want to use `erase`

```
size_t first = str.find("[");
size_t last = str.find("]", first);
str.erase(first,last-first+1);
```

Remember you'll need to check that neither first or last are equal to `std::npos`

Comment: dvar_hostname = "[12]1234";
    string str = string(dvar_hostname);
    size_t first = str.find("]");
    size_t last = str.find("[", first);
    str.erase(first,last-first);
    const char* tempHostName = str.c_str();
    printf("tempHostName: %s\n", tempHostName);//this printed out "[12"

Comment: @SyxDuLappen use something like http://ideone.com, run the code, and link it to us.

Comment: @SyxDuLappen apologies, I hadn't actually run the code, just edited to fix order and out by one error.

Comment: this is my code: http://prntscr.com/bcpavb and this is the outcome: http://prntscr.com/bcpaqu

Answer (score 1):

Why not this very simple solution, using the tried and true `for` loop and a boolean?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void ChangeString(std::string& test)
{
    bool inbracket = false;
    std::string outStr;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < test.size(); ++i)
    { 
        char ch = test[i];
        if (ch == '[') 
           inbracket = true;
        else
        if ( ch == ']')
           inbracket = false;
        else
        if ( !inbracket )
           outStr += ch;
     }
     test = outStr;
}

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    std::string test = "[12]1234[56]78";
    ChangeString(test);
    cout << test;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/GqZvtc)

I know it doesn't use all sorts of `std::string` functions, but sometimes to solve a problem, you just have to take a step back and resort to what would usually seem to be the most obvious way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    const char * dvar_hostname = "[12]1234";
    std::string host = std::string(dvar_hostname);
    std::size_t pos = host.find("]");
    const char *tempHostName = host.substr(pos+1).c_str();
    std::cout << tempHostName;
}
```

proof it's working: http://ideone.com/a4bI83

Comment: Except it will be removed even if the first character is something else and it doesn't erase it multiple times, and if the right bracket isn't in it it'll crash?

Comment: well of course you need to check if this find is not equal to npos.

Comment: What about the string "124[12]123"? It'll remove the beginning "124" when it's not supposed to.

Comment: dvar_hostname = "[12]1234";
    std::string host = std::string(dvar_hostname);
    std::size_t pos = host.find("]");
    const char *tempHostName = host.substr(pos+1).c_str();
    printf("tempHostName: %s\n", tempHostName); //this printed out nothing

Comment: @coyotte508 yes it will delete first part as well. If [] can be in the middle then just use erase from David answer. To the second problem, of course in production code you need to check if std::find didn't return npos. This was smallest code to show example solution.

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
bool end = false;

size_t pos_open = 0;
size_t pos_close = 0;

const char *dvar_hostname = "123[456]79[88]";
string dh(dvar_hostname);//get string value
while(!end){
    pos_open = dh.find('[');
    pos_close = dh.find(']');

    if(pos_open == string::npos || pos_close == string::npos || pos_close < pos_open){
        end = true;
    }else{
        dh.erase(pos_open, pos_close - pos_open + 1);
    }
}

dvar_hostname = dh.c_str();//convert back
cout << dvar_hostname;
```

Working example: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/60nVlH)

---

I improved it a lit bit:

```
bool open_bracket = true;
bool terminate = false;

size_t pos_open = 0;
size_t pos_close = 0;
size_t last = 0;

const char *dvar_hostname = "123]][][[[[456]79[88][[";
string dh(dvar_hostname);//get string value
while(!terminate){
    string temp = dh.substr(last);
    pos_open = temp.find('[');
    pos_close = temp.find(']');

    terminate = (pos_open == string::npos || pos_close == string::npos);

    if(!terminate && pos_close > pos_open){
            dh.erase(pos_open + last, pos_close - pos_open + 1);
    }else if(pos_open != string::npos || pos_close < pos_open){
        last += pos_open;
    }else if(pos_close != string::npos){
        last += pos_close;
    }
}

dvar_hostname = dh.c_str();//convert back
cout << dvar_hostname;
```

This will output `"123]]79[["`
[Ideone](http://ideone.com/M0Vheq)

Comment: No it doesn't :) "123][12]123", it won't erase the "[12]"

Comment: ily <3 thx so much :) EDIT: it's fine like this the text will always start with brackets...